# Wifi adapter not found BCM4352 / 14e4:43b1 please help ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, broadcom

I am completely new to Linux and have converted an old Asus G750JW. Unfortunately I have been unable to get my wireless network adapter to work. I have tried all the threads I have been able to find that's related but have been unable to fix it.

```
~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dd400000-dd407fff memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 74:d0:2b:1a:c8:c5
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:dd500000-dd53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Edit:
After following -
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4
lspci: -d: ':' expected

after following the other thread that's the only thing I have found that has changed.

Comment: What OS & release are you running?

Comment: sorry forgot to include OS 20.04.1 LTS